# Difference in compiling in GCC and LLVM GCC Compiler

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ipad

I am developing iPhone application which is using the 3 projects. One project is developed with the combination of c and c++ code and one is on Objective C and one is to link both (Objective-C and C and C++ project) the project.

Now when I am compiling my C and C++ project in GCC compiler it compiles perfectly but when I am compiling the same project with LLVM-GCC compiler it's throwing error of 'Initilizer element is not a constant'.

```
#define MY_WSD const

struct FuncDef {
  i8 nArg;             
  u8 iPrefEnc;         
  u8 needCollSeq;      
  u8 flags;            
  void *pUserData;     
  FuncDef *pNext;      
  char *zName;
  FuncDef *pHash;
};

typedef struct FuncDef FuncDef;

#define FUNCTION(zName, nArg, iArg, bNC, xFunc) \
  {nArg, SQLITE_UTF8, bNC, 0, SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(iArg), 0, xFunc, 0, 0, #zName}
```

Here is the code responsible for error:

```
void myDateTimeFunctions(void){
    static MY_WSD FuncDef aDateTimeFuncs[] = {
    FUNCTION(julianday,        -1, 0, 0, juliandayFunc ), //when I compile the code with LLVM GCC it's giving me error 
                                                          //at this line and the later line and working fine with GCC 
                                                          //alone compiler. But the problem is XCode 4.2 does not come 
                                                          //with GCC alone compiler, so I am unable to run the applciation.
    FUNCTION(date,             -1, 0, 0, dateFunc      ),
  };
```

Please let me know if I am missing some valuable info for the bug to be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thanks for your all supports and answer I got the answer of the question. It was the problem with the macro SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR  defined in sqlite.c and it was the problem rreported long back with the LLVM_GCC compiler. Actually it is needed to redefine the macro and it will solve the problem.

Here is the reference for the same: http://tribelet.blogspot.com/2008/09/blog-post_08.html
language of the post is Japanese but it helped me to get out of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that `SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(iArg)` is non constant when using the LLVM compiler and you therefore have illegal code.

Do you see the same error if you compile with straight gcc using the `--std=c99` switch?  If you do, try running your gcc-LLVM compile with `--std=gnu99` to see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Yes the error is same when I am using --std=c99 as C language dialect in build settings.

Comment: Yes @Jeremy I tried with all available option to compile. It does not solve my problem.

Comment: But I am agree that problem is there in  SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(iArg), but when I try with other compiler option I am not able to get rid of the problem. Can you provide me some more hit and trial on it.

Comment: @KPT: I think I would proceed by substituting the `SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR(iArg)` by its expansion and cutting bits out of it until it compiles.  That will tell you exactly what is wrong.  You'll have to be careful because the LLVM compiler might cause it to be defined differently to the standard gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any warnings before the error? One guess would be that `SQLITE_INT_TO_PTR` is not defined and defaults to a function call.

Otherwise try `llvm-gcc -E` on the file (you might have to look in your Xcode build log to get the complete line) to see what it compiles into.

Comment: There is no warning before the error. Please let me know how can I provide this compiler option llvm-gcc -E. As I explained in one of the answer that there are limited C Dialect I can use, and I tried every dialect it's not working on any one of them.